# Proof that the pre-image of an open set is open

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was wondering if my current progress is reasonable and if someone can lead me more to the result.
Let $f$ : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous mapping. Prove that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is open, $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open for $\epsilon, \delta >0$.

This is my progress.
let $z \in f^{-1}(U)$.
since $f$ is continuous, then by definition,
$\forall z \in \mathbb{R}^n $; the ball $B_{d}(z,\delta) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \implies B_{d}(f(z),\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m.$
and since $U$ is open
then let $x \in U \implies B_{d}(x,\Delta) \subseteq U$ for all $\Delta >0$.

Where can I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of on the right track I think. Here is the way you should think of it:

For any $\epsilon>0$, by definition of continuity there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x\in B_d(z,\delta)$ implies $f(x)\in B_d(f(z),\epsilon)$. In particular, since $U$ is open you can choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_d(f(z),\epsilon)\subset U$. Now apply the above fact to show that $B_d(z,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(U)$ for some $\delta$.

Comment: So if  $x\in B_d(z,\delta)$ implies $f(x)\in B_d(f(z),\epsilon)$ then also $f(x) \in f(B_d(z,\delta))$ by taking the image of both sides on the LHS of the implication, I have to prove $f(B_d(z,\delta)) \subseteq B_d(f(z),\epsilon)$? How would I do this?